# What is turnip in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is turnip in Ruby? Can someone provide insight on turnip in Ruby and how they are related to feature files?

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip?

Comment: Are you talking about [`ruby turnip`](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+turnip)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [jnicklas/turnip](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip).

> Turnip is a Gherkin extension for RSpec. It allows you to write tests in Gherkin and run them through your RSpec environment. Basically you can write cucumber features in RSpec.

Gherkin language is what you use when you write [cucumber](http://cukes.info/) tests. Turnip allow you to write these tests without depending on the [cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber) gem, i.e., you can use [RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) for all testing purposes.